# Unity FPS microgame scripts can't find custom scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the FPS Microgame base to create a basic game in unity. The version I'm using is 2020.3.01f. I've made sure both scripts use the same namespace. If I make another new script, it can find my script but the ones that come with the microgame can not. I'm trying to reach it by using the following code:

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<MyScript>().RunMyFunction();
```

I would prefer not to scrap the entire collision system the microgame comes with if possible. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: `I've made sure both scripts use the same namespace` could you post your scripts and are there maybe any [Assembly Definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) involved? If you select the scripts you can see which assembly it belongs to in the Inspector (see [Finding which assembly a script belongs to](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#find-assembly)) if they are in different assemblies they might not know each other -> Add a dependency to the other assembly in your assembly definition

Comment: Are you sure the object you are colliding with doesnt have children and the component is not on that instead?

Comment: `Unity FPS microgame scripts can't find custom scripts` What are the actual errors you get when trying to `GetComponent<CustomComponent>()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have placed your Collision System files under plugin folder. Unity has a build order system which separates projects from each other. If I recall correctly, you can't reference Plugin folder scripts from Asset scripts since Unity compiles each of them as a different project. [See if this link helps.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html)

Answer (score 0):

The FPS Microgame defines multiple [assemblies](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html).  The FPS Microgame cannot directly reference custom code unless:

A) The custom code is placed into an assembly that is referenced by the particular FPS assembly being modified.  (Recommended)

B) The FPS assembly definition(s) are removed.